# How can $P(X+Y=\alpha)=1$ and $(X,Y)$ independent imply that $X$ and $Y$ are constant?

Tags: probability-theory, independence

This is an exercise in Jacod and Protter's [*Probability Essentials*](http://books.google.com/books?id=OK_d-w18EVgC&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=%22Show+that+both+X+and+Y+are+constant+random%22&source=bl&ots=GFiiYsjllV&sig=HnGN5MVRlxyn_rOygJY0XmYiKmo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=COF9UNWMBonm8gS1roGADQ&sqi=2&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22Show%20that%20both%20X%20and%20Y%20are%20constant%20random%22&f=false):

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables and $P(X+Y=\alpha)=1$ where $\alpha\in{\Bbb R}$ is some constant. Show that both $X$ and $Y$ are constant random variables.

What I think is that one might use Borel-Cantelli theorem here. Since
$$
\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty}\{X=i,Y=\alpha-i\}\subset\{X+Y=\alpha\}=\bigcup_{\beta\in{\Bbb R}}\{X=\beta,Y=\alpha-\beta\},
$$
we have
$$
\begin{align}
P\bigg(\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty}\{X=i,Y=\alpha-i\}\bigg)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}P(X=i,Y=\alpha-i)<\infty
\end{align}
$$
But this seems to give nothing. Also, I'm surprised about the result is that $X=\gamma$ for some constant $\gamma$ instead of $P(X=\gamma)=1$. Any idea about how I can go on?

Comment: I think that what is meant by $X$ being a constant variable is exactly that $P(X=\gamma)=1$ for some $\gamma$ and not that $X=\gamma$ pointwise.

Answer (score 2):

By assumption, $X=\alpha-Y $ almost surely. Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, so are $X$ and $\alpha-Y$ by properties of independent random variables. It follows that $X$ is independent with itself, which implies that
$$
P(X\leq x)=P(X\leq x,\ X\leq x)=[P(X\leq x)]^2,\quad x\in{\Bbb R}.
$$
Therefore, $P(X\leq x)=0$ or $1$. Using the properties of probability distribution function one can show (exercise) that $X$ be a constant (almost surely).

Answer (score 0):

If $X+Y=\alpha$ then $X=\alpha-Y$.  The random variable $Y$ cannot be independent of $\alpha-Y$, since as $Y$ gets bigger, $\alpha-Y$ gets smaller and as $Y$ gets smaller, $\alpha-Y$ gets bigger.  Unless, of course, $Y$ never gets bigger or smaller.